# OmdB API does not show result in my TextViews

Tags: android, json

I'm brand new to Android Development and have taken fresh start with some widgets etc. I'm reached to a point where I have to display OmDB API data into my Activity's TextViews and ImageView. I'm using JSON for showing data into TextViews.

Here is my code for XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etMovieName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter Movie Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Search"
        />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMovieYear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Year"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMovieActor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Actors"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMovieDirector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Directors"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMovieCountry"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Countries"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMovieLanguage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Languages"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvMoviePlot"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="PLot"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgPoster"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

And here is my References to Widgets:

```
EditText edtMovieName;
Button btnSearchMovie;
TextView tvYear, tvActor, tvDirector, tvCountry, tvLanguage, tvPlot;
ImageView ivPoster;
```

Then I have OnCreate and My Button Click Event Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies_database);

    edtMovieName = findViewById(R.id.etMovieName);

    btnSearchMovie = findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);

    tvYear = findViewById(R.id.tvMovieYear);
    tvActor = findViewById(R.id.tvMovieActor);
    tvDirector = findViewById(R.id.tvMovieDirector);
    tvCountry = findViewById(R.id.tvMovieCountry);
    tvLanguage = findViewById(R.id.tvMovieLanguage);
    tvPlot = findViewById(R.id.tvMoviePlot);

    ivPoster = findViewById(R.id.imgPoster);


btnSearchMovie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String movieName = edtMovieName.getText().toString();
            if(movieName.isEmpty())
            {
                edtMovieName.setError("Please Enter Movie Name");
                return;
            }

            String url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=" + movieName + "&plot=full&apikey=e03663ba";

            RequestQueue RQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(MoviesDatabaseActivity.this);

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,

                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                                String strMovieYear = jObj.getString(response);

                                String tru = "True";

                                if(strMovieYear.equals(tru))
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOT Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }
            );
            RQ.add(strReq);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Question**

The problem with this code is, when I run the App so after pressing the Search Button, nothing comes up in Toasts. I rechecked the code and followed the same thing over and over again nothing displayed in Toasts.

I've surely found some relevant OmDB codes, but could not help me.

Comment: Do you have any errors in logs or in the onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) method?

Comment: NO. I don't get any kind of error.